# Error: Mapping an object with an integrated react-icon

Tags: javascript, react-icons

I've got an object that I'm trying to map over. I keep getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at
> navigation.js?t=1663213543000:18:11).

It's referring to the icon. It should work though...
React-Icons "^4.4.0" is installed.

Here's a sandbox recreation without the issue...

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-sholnc?file=/src/navigation.js

[image]

**navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { RiContactsLine } from 'react-icons/ri';

export const links = [
   {
      title: 'Dashboard',
      links: [
           {
              name: 'ecommerce',
              icon: <RiContactsLine />,
           },
      ],
   }
]
```

If I comment out the icon line, it'll display Dashboard and ecommerce, but won't render with the icon line included.
Here's the file that maps over it:

**Sidebar.jsx**

```
import { links } from '../../Data/navigation.js';
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = () => {

  return (

    <div className="sidebar-container">
        <div className="sidebar shadow-md">

            {links.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.title}>
                <p className="text-gray-400 m-3 mt-4 uppercase title">
                  {item.title}
                </p>
                {item.links.map((link) => (
                  <NavLink 
                    to={`/${link.name}`}
                    key={link.name}
                  >
                      {link.icon}
                      <span className="capitalize">
                          {link.name}
                      </span>
                  </NavLink>
                ))}
               </div>
              ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You said, if you out comment the icon, the icon is not displayed? What exactly is the problem with that? Maybe it also helps if you attach the file after you did your change that causes an error.

Comment: @ViktorLuft Nothing of course, Just trying to describe what works and what doesn't. Deleted node-modules and I got this  on npm start: "✘ [ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled    src/Data/navigation.js:22:22:
      22 │                 icon: <BiColorFill />," (This is a vite setup.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. After deleting node_modules and reinstalling, I received this error.

> "✘ [ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled
> src/Data/navigation.js:22:22: 22 │ icon: ,"

After following this link: https://badcodernocookie.com/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled/

It looks like it had something to do with Vite...

I changed the filename to navigation.jsx, created the .babelrc file in the main directory, and installed those 2 dependencies. Hope this can help someone!